# Breeze delete failing, json has mysterious "undefined": false

Tags: breeze

I am making a website that follows John Papa's Code Camper SPA Jumpstart Pluralsight course.  My database/entities has the following hierarchy:

- Proficiency contains Action(s) and Level(s).

When I delete a "Proficiency", I get the following **server** side error:
"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Looking at the json JObject saveBundle in the BreezeController, I am seeing a mysterious:

> "undefined": false,

in every entity.  None of my entities have a Boolean in them.  Just like in Code Camper, I am adding an "isPartial" in the constructor of each entity as shown in the code below.

```
        var proficiencyConstructor = function () {
        this.isPartial = false;
    }

        metadataStore.registerEntityTypeCtor('Proficiency', proficiencyConstructor, proficiencyInitializer);


    function proficiencyInitializer(proficiency) {
    var empty = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000";
    if (proficiency.id() === empty) {
        proficiency.id(breeze.core.getUuid());
    }
};
```

My gut says the mysterious "undefined":false  is the "isPartial" property.  According to the [documentation](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/extending-entities), the "Breeze adds the isPartial property to the Entity metadata as an unmapped property. The values of unmapped properties are **not** transmitted to the service."  I am stuck.  Anyone recommend things I can do to figure this out?

Thanks,
Dan

Here is a sample from the savebundle

> {  "entities": 
>       [
>       {       "Id": "a0223d7c-35e5-458f-ba83-65ec7ec189fa",      "Name": "AST Prof0",      "IsEnabled": true,      "Description": "AST Prof0",      "ProficiencyType": "TBD",      "ApplicationId": "7ba4b47f-06a3-4ceb-bca6-de3fd3699bbd",      "undefined": false,      "entityAspect": {        "entityTypeName": "Proficiency:#LobGame.Model",        "entityState": "Deleted",        "originalValuesMap": {          "IsPartial": true        },        "autoGeneratedKey": null      }    },

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is likely due to a bug fix that is now in breeze 1.2.8. This fixed it for me.

From their release notes:

> Bug fix for the case where a save involving a delete would fail when
>   that save also involved a modification to an unmapped property.

http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/download